# Redrawing a UIView with animation

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics, core-animation

I am a novice ios programmer & I am doing my first ios project. In my project I have several `UIView` and `UIViewController`. In each view I have overriden `drawRect` method and drawn several circles. In one my view  I need to draw a rectangle and when I touch it, it would draw another 3 rectangles beneath it with animation. I was wondering what would be the best way to do it! I was thinking to redraw the view after touch by calling `setNeedsDisplay` and draw the other three rectangles with animation. How can I achieve this and what else method would be best to perform this particular thing with animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding drawRect may not be the best solution for you because to accomplish many types of animations you'll need to redraw many times under a timer.  Beyond that, your drawing will be done with the CPU, you won't get to take advantage of any hardware acceleration.

I suggest that before the three new rectangles are visible you add three UIViews to the view hierarchy in the places those rectangles should be.  Set the `backgroundColor` property of each view to the color of rectangle you want and set the `alpha` value of each view to 0.  When it's time to animate the rectangles into view, you can then use code like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    rectView1.alpha = 1.0;
    rectView2.alpha = 1.0;
    rectView3.alpha = 1.0;
}];
```

Of course change the duration of the animation fit your application, and you can change other properties of the rectViews as well.  Suppose you want the rects to fade in *and* fly in from the sides.  You can accomplish that by adjusting the `frame` property of each rectView before the animation and then inside the animations block.

Comment: Great solution.but i have some questions..*should I need to use `setneedsdisplay` in this situation?  and where can declare those three `uiview` without being  called first time loading the whole view

Comment: You need to call setNeedsDisplay when you want to force a view to redraw with drawRect, but if you are just manipulating the subviews of view then you do *not* need to cause the parent view to redraw, and in fact calling setNeedsDisplay will probably just hurt your program's performance.